# How do I enhance the effect of trypophobia?

Tags: shapes, perception, psychology

For a project using synthetic images ([styleGAN](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan) to be precise), I'm looking at many different manifestations of an eye. Displaying them on a grid unintentionally created a [trypophobia-like](https://www.google.com/search?q=Trypophobia) (fear of small holes) feel.

I don’t have any background in art, and I'm very curious to how this image evokes a particular response – and how I can make it stronger.
**What can I do to increase this effect?** Adding the black lines seems to help a good deal, as they highlight the contrast between them.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to increase the effect! This is question about perception and what can be done artistically to enhance this (unpleasant) feeling. Not having any background in art, I'm very curious to how this image evokes a particular response -- and how I can make it stronger. (side note: I looked at the guidelines for this site and it _seems_ to be on-topic, but I'll close if it's not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what dispels the overall trypophobia the most are the larger hazel eyes that are much lighter than the other eyes. Matching skin tone values would also help a little more.